# How to install Microsoft Office on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, microsoft-office

I have been trying to install Office on Ubuntu 18.04 but none of the previous methods work. 
[This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf8zr096mYQ) specifically does not work.

Here are the steps to the problem:

1. New ubuntu 18.04 install on Thinkpad X1 carbon - fully updated and working
2. `sudo apt-get install playonlinux winbind -y`
3. In PlayonLinux I start a new Office 2010 install.
4. The software installs wine and then hangs on creating the virtual drive - "Please wait while the virtual drive is being created..."

I would be grateful if someone could help with this.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What exactly has failed in your case? What output did you get? Please [edit] your question and be as specific as possible. Or you might want to give [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) a chance.

Comment: Hi, Melebius. I use both LibreOffice and MS Office. For certain pivot table features the latter is preferred by a client and I need to support them.

Comment: Hi, I was successful with these steps:

1. sudo apt-get install playonlinux winbind -y

2. Using play on linux wine manager I installed wine 3.8 (32-bit)

3. Created new 32-bit virtual disk with wine 3.8

4. Installed riched20 dotnet20 msxml6 and microsoft core fonts there using pol component setup

5. Ran exe with office setup from this disk

Credit to https://askubuntu.com/a/1041342/829660

Sorry, I could not figure out proper formatting of the comment.

Comment: Glad you have solved your issue. Please upvote the answer you found successful. And if an answer to another question solved your issue, you should vote to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, @Melebius, I do not seem to have rights to do any upvoting or closing.