# How to install Office 2010 32 bit on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wine, 18.04, microsoft-office

I am trying to install MS Office 2010 32bit on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Following is my Wine version:

```
wine --version    
wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
```

When I run setup.exe I am getting following in the log. And installation stops. Can I get some tip, how can I make it work? Should I re-install Wine?

```
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:msi:ITERATE_WriteRegistryValues Could not create key L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\CTF\\TIP\\{70FAF614-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\Category\\Category\\{70FAF615-E0B1-11D3-8F5C-00C04F9CF4AC}\\{A8BA876D-E619-11D3-8F5D-00C04F9CF4A0}"
0094:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"WriteRegistryValues" returned 1627
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0094:err:rpc:RpcAssoc_BindConnection rejected bind for reason 0
008c:err:rpc:RpcAssoc_BindConnection rejected bind for reason 0
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried PlayOnLinux. It says that MS Office 2010 works. https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-3-0.html

Comment: @arochester on POL, I am getting this error: [POL_Wine] Error: Wine seems to have crashed. I have tried re-installing WINE and POL both. Not sure how to sort it out.

Comment: I have uploaded a video showing how do this, try it, good luck.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLpwOt7nd5g

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same problem with wine/POL during recent office 2010 installation. I solved it in a following way:

1) Using play on linux wine manager I installed wine 3.8 (32-bit)

2) Created new 32-bit virtual disk with wine 3.8

3) Installed riched20 dotnet20 msxml6 there using pol component setup

4) Ran exe with office setup from this disk

Comment: Amazing! I had been getting crazy with this for the last couple of hours. 

I may add that if you want to have the apps pop up in your dash search, or if you want to make certain files open by default with the office apps, you must: 

1st) make a shortcut for the apps (word, powerpoint, whatever) with configure > [your virtual drive] > General > Make a new shortcut..., and then choosing the .exe in question. 
2nd) follow step by step what is said [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940522)

Comment: Had to also install winbind (sudo apt install winbind)

Answer (score 0):

Try with Playonlinux. It will install all the necessary libraries.
I suggest testing the WPS. Fully compatible with Office formatting.

Comment: Not having luck with PlayonLinux also. I re-installed Wine and POL. And getting this error in POL: [POL_Wine] Error: Wine seems to have crashed

Comment: Sorry... test WPS

Answer (score 0):

I did too, the other way when you chose the setup file, a window with no items shows, but the option is there.

I just slid the window by pressing TAB and the right or down bottons. I don't remember clearly which, but press TAB and the arrows, as you are showing the options.

You can view a video about the installation in Ubuntu 16.04 and the options shows, and you knows how press TAB and the arrows.

[image]

Comment: If some one need help just, and the image above is to watch that works